# AWS Amplify React Customize User Input

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Is there anyway to customize the username which a user enters in AWS Amplify? I am creating a multi-tenant app suit in which a user may belong to more than 1 tenant. That tenant may have different authentication requirements, such as `TenantSMSMFA` using SMS for MFA, and `TenantTOTP` using TOTP.

It's possible that a user with the same email might exist in different organization, with a different account and different settings and use different apps, so ideally I would like to be able to prefix the `username` such as : `TenantSMSMFA-usera@test.com` & `TenantTOTP-userb@test.com`. A bit of a silly requirement but trying to avoid creating more than one user pool if I can. For example say there is a contractor who is doing work at CustomerA with their private email address as their username, and then move to CustomerB, currently CustomerB could not create their account again because it would be conflicting with an existing account.